# Checking if two geometric distributions have the same mean

Tags: r, python, mean, geometric-distribution

I have 2 geometric distributions. And I have to compare their means and get the p-value. Is there a statistical test specifically designed for geometric distributions? I already used Mann-Whitney for non-parametric distributions, and resampling. But a test for geometric distributions might yield better results. Is there any solution in python or R?